# Calling an overriden parent method is throwing an undefined property error

Tags: php

I am trying to bypass an override method but getting an error:

> Notice: Undefined property: EventPositionModel::$parent

I am calling like this:

```
$newEventPosition = new EventPositionModel;
$newEventPosition::parent->createRecord($accessUser, $fieldValues);

//also tried
$newEventPosition->parent::createRecord($accessUser, $fieldValues);
```

The object is set.

I have also tried `$newEventPosition->parent->createRecord`

The classes are:

```
class EventPositionModel extends Model {
     public function createRecord($accessUser, $fieldValues){
        //we need to know if we are creating for one or all days
        $recordCreated = false;

        if (!empty($fieldValues['all_days'])){
             // we need to loop the scheduled days and add the position
             $eventSchedule = new EventScheduleModel;
             $eventScheduleDays = $eventSchedule->getAllChildRecords();

             foreach($eventScheduleDays as $scheduleDay){
                $fieldValues['event_schedule_id'] = $scheduleDay['event_scheduleID'];

                // Because I need to return a JSON array to the API caller I need to create seperate instances of the same model for each record created at this point.
                $newEventPosition = new EventPositionModel;
                if ($newEventPosition::parent::createRecord($accessUser, $fieldValues)){
                    $this->record['newPositions'] = $newEventPosition->record;

                };
            }
        }
        else{
            if (parent::createRecord($accessUser, $fieldValues)){
                  //do some stuff....
            }
         }

     }
}


class Model{
    public function createRecord($accessUser, $fieldValues){
         //Do a LOT of stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please add your *EventPositionModel* class code here for better understanding

Comment: You can't call an overridden parent method from outside the subclass. It's not clear *why* you're trying to do this. That you are trying it suggests a flaw in your model design.

Comment: Ok. So it can't be done. I will come up with an alternative. Thank you.